# iText - is it possible to parse text within a given width and height specific area?

Tags: parsing, text, itext

I'm using iText version 5 and would like to know if this is possible for documents and if so how would I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer suffice or are there still any open points?

Comment: Your answer is sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: In that case please accept it (click the tick at its upper left) to mark it as sufficiently answered.

Comment: I’ve actually already tried to but “Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.”

Comment: Not the arrows, the tick underneath! (You might need to hover over it to see it clearly.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example for that task on the iText web site: [ExtractPageContentArea](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15#564-extractpagecontentarea.java).

The pivotal code:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(70, 80, 490, 580);
RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
    out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy));
}
out.flush();
out.close();
reader.close();
```

This example stores the text from the (hard coded) rectangle in a file but you can obviously also handle it differently.